# Migrated flag in the question title does not give the direction of migration

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Given the rising amount of migrated question, I think it would be nice to have flags in the title like `[migrated from xy]` or `[migrated to wz]` giving the direction of migration.

Is this easy to implement and a sensible addition to the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current `[migrated]` postfix to a title only ever shows up on the source site.

That is, the site the post was migrated *from*.

The destination site doesn't show it - nor can I think of a good reason to show it.

---

So, in a sense, this is already done - if you see `[migrated]` at the end of a post, you know it has been migrated away.